# AfterEffects DOF simulation

Tags: opengl, adobe, effects, after-effects

I am trying to re - create Adobe AfterEffects DOF (depth of field) in OpenGL using [post - processing technique](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch23.html).My DOF works great.But I am having a hard time to match the DOF parameters so that the visuals look the same on both sides.
In fact **Focus Distance** and **Aperture**( Focus Length) seem to be the same, but I can't figure out
what **Blur Level** property  means in AE?I tried to match it with maximum blur radius on my side,but it doesn't seem to work the same.It is measured in percentage.But percentage relative to what? Anyone has an idea how AE DOF **Blur Level** is calculated,or on which algorithm AE DOF is based?

Comment: [According to the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/aftereffects/cs/using/WS3878526689cb91655866c1103906c6dea-7e29a.html) - "Blur Level - The amount of depth-of-field blur in an image. A setting of 100% creates a natural blur as dictated by the camera settings. Lower values reduce the blur." So it seems like it's a percentage of whatever the real value would be for a given camera if it were a real physical camera.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link will help to understand a little about values in Ae
http://www.trapcode-content.com/help/form/Source_Files/mblur.html

also this link may explain a little DOF (because it explain cameras in Ae so there are REAL values that measure DOF that you're looking for) http://tv.adobe.com/watch/after-effects-cs55-new-creative-techniques/ae-cs55-3d-camera-depth-of-field-parameters/